# How to allow Mac OS X's native Apache/PHP installation to access WebServer directories?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mac-osx, web-server

I have a problem bugging me with Mac OS X's native Apache/PHP installation.

With my PHP scripts, I have to alter the file permissions on each folder I want to access. For example, in an upload script I would have to set the destination directory to 'read & write' for the group 'everyone'. However, I believe this is not the best practice and would like all of my directories to be readily writable to PHP.

My scripts are stored in `/Library/WebServer/Documents/`, which is Mac OS X's default directory to serve web pages locally.

Comment: Consider rethinking your approach -- making all directories writable to the webserver process is rarely a good practice.  I've helped clean up a number of hosts in this last year where a bad shell script allowed a remote user to insert an 'index.php' that looked to serve what had previously been in 'index.html', but would serve viagra ads when called with a QUERY_STRING.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are running the client version? The server is running as user _www, group _www, so your files/dirs must be accessible at least for the _www group, not for everyone.